# How to disallow child to access parent action method in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance

I have studied inheritance in ASP.net MVC, and I got a problem while using it.

**Parent:**

```
public class ParentTestController
{
    [httpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [httpPost]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if(//condition)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index","ChildTest");
        }
        else {return View();}
    }
}
```

**Child:**

```
public class ChildTestController : ParentTestController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //somemodel
        return View(//somemodel);
    }
}
```

The program always read `Index` from parent class.

Can I access `Index` in child instead of in parent? I have tried changing `public` to `private`, but this causes a lot of errors. Is there any way to access `Index` from child?

Comment: Why does `ChildTestController` inherit from `ParentTestController`?

Comment: And why doesn't ParentTestController inherit from Controller? and the Http action verbs decorating the controller actions do not have the correct capitalization.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Cause, i have a lot method in grandparent which inheritance to `ParentTestController`

Comment: The create a `BaseController: Controller` for any common code. The both `ParentTestController` and `ChildTestController` inherit from `BaseController`

Comment: @Fran my mistake ParentTestController : GrandParentController,

Comment: @StephenMuecke , yeah something like that, but can i call Index in `ChildTestController ` from  `ParentTestController ` using RedirectToAction()?

Comment: Yes. Your `BaseController` will not contain any `ActionResult` methods (just `protected` properties/methods that the derived `ParentTestController` and `ChildTestController` will use

Comment: Also, why are there two methods with the exact same signature?

Comment: Maybe flip the inheritance. It's like this: "a father was once a son, but a son was never a father"

Answer (score 1):

Because the Parent Method was not marked as `virtual` the compiler will actually be showing a warning that you have overloaded a method that has not been declared as overloadable. As a check mechanism, when overloading you must state if you are declaring a `new` implementation to use instead of the parent.

> **Warning**   *CS0108*    'ChildTestController .Index()' hides inherited member 'ParentTestController
>   .Index()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

## Solution 1:

Mark the Index on the parent as `virtual`, this means that you intend for this method to be overridden by child classes, then also declare the overriding method in the child class as an `override`.

Implication of this notation: When you cast the child object as the parent type, the child implementation of the method will be invoked.

```
ChildTestController child = new ChildTestController(); 
(child as ParentTestController).Index();
// will return the view
```

**Parent**

```
[httpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
    if(//condition)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index","ChildTest");
    }
    else {return View();}
}
```

__ Child__

```
[httpPost]
public override ActionResult Index()
{
    //somemodel
    return View(//somemodel);
}
```

## Solution 2:

You can forcibly mark the Index on the child as a `new` implementation to replace that of the parent class, but only this type will know about this behaviour.

Implication of this notation: When you cast the child object as the parent type, the parent implementation of the method will be invoked, because the parent implementation does not specifically allow the method to be overridden.

```
ChildTestController child = new ChildTestController(); 
(child as ParentTestController).Index();
// will redirect, as you have already demonstrated.
```

When is it viable to use this... I would reserve this for advanced scenarios, it means that if your child class is inherited by grandchild, then grandchild still inherits the parent implementation of Index, and not the specific implementation in the child class.

**Child**

```
[httpPost]
public new ActionResult Index()
{
    //somemodel
    return View(//somemodel);
}
```

Comment: Remember to check your compiler warnings, some developers like to set the compiler option to treat warnings as errors to help keep the code clean, it is even a company policy at some places I have worked at. `listen to your friend the compiler, he's a cool dude.`

Comment: This may(?) solve OP's issue, but the real problem is OP's design and inheritance chain. A controller should not inherit from another controller containing `public ActionResult` methods.

Comment: I have many controllers that inherit, it is certainly not the norm, but more than acceptable. Without seeing the rest of OPs structure its hard to comment, but I think you'll find OP was specifically testing the concept of inheritance, rather than this being a real world solution.